# Run a local script on a remote server using ssh with out having to worry about quotes

Tags: ssh, bash

So I have been running local scripts fine on a remote server:

```
ssh user@server "`cat local-script.sh`"
```

However, today I have a script that has both single and double quotes in it. Which causes the script to fail because the output of `cat local-script.sh` is wrapped in quotes. With out modifying the script itself, is there a better way to handle this?

I thought this may work:

```
ssh user@server $(<local-script.sh)
```

But is does not seem to do anything...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the following test script:

```
#!/bin/bash
uname -n
a=(b c 'd e' f)
echo "${#a[@]}"
b=(1 "2 3" 4)
echo "${#b[@]}"
```

The output should be the remote host name followed by 4 and 3 when executed using:

```
ssh user@server "$(<scriptname)"
```

This shows that the quotes inside the script are being handled correctly. If the quotes weren't being handled correctly, the numbers output would be 5 and 4 due to word splitting. Note the quotes around the command substitution.

By the way, the first command you posted doesn't work. The single quotes prevent the backticks from being evaluated locally.

Comment: You are correct about the single quotes. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: I have awarded the correct answer to you, because it was closest to what I originally had. I was just missing the quotes. Also because you provided a testable script.

Answer (score 8):

```
cat local-script.sh | ssh user@server bash
```

or whatever shell you want to use instead of bash

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the script is in file script.sh.  What the heck is the problem with running:

```
 ssh -T user@remote.host.com <script.sh
```

This works for me!

Comment: That's not doing what the OP wants.

Comment: Corrected.........

Comment: What is the difference between `<script.sh` and `$(<script.sh)` ?

Comment: See the message from Dennis Williamson.  I still go for simplicity, why involve more work for a program to do when a simpler construct can do the same and is far readable too.

Comment: @MichaelIrey: The difference is that a message stating that a pseudo-terminal is not allocated because of the redirection. You can suppress the resulting message by adding the `-T` option to your `ssh` command.

Comment: changed as requested...